Duplicate environment names in Anaconda Navigator
It seems that I have duplicate environment names in Anaconda Navigator(AN)

History:
I wiped my entire drive and reinstalled all my apps last night. SSD was malfunctioning due to other issues (I messed up the WinRE partition, etc). Anyways before the wipe, I had copied the contents of the conda related directories to another drive. I should say that AN was working fine with no duplicate environment names. I then downloaded a fresh new copy of AN and then copied the older saved contents to the appropriate folders in the new AN directories. It overwrote files of the same name.
I have followed the solution listed here and it helped a bit but still problem exists. I get the following below:
(base) C:\Users\User>conda config --show envs_dirs
envs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\User\.conda\envs
  - C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
  - C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs

The contents of my environments list at C:\Users\user\.conda\environments.txt is shown below (thanks to the solution above):
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\Torch
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\TF_GPU
C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\Torch_GPU


---------------------------------------------
When I type the following, I still get this:
---------------------------------------------

(base) C:\Users\User>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
TF_GPU                   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\TF_GPU
Torch                    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Torch
Torch_GPU                C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Torch_GPU
TF_GPU                   C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\TF_GPU
Torch                    C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\Torch
Torch_GPU                C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\Torch_GPU

How can I fix this as I'm clueless to what am I doing wrong. Thanks!
